# How to verify a user's email when adding a new user with add-user-keycloak.sh?

Tags: php, docker, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-admin-cli

We are currently adding default Keycloak users in the following way:

`/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -r realm-name -u admin@test.com -p admin`

However, when I attempt to generate a bearer token like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://auth.server-name.localhost/auth/realms/realm-name/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin@test.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=my-clien-id'
```

I get the following error response:

`{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Account is not fully set up"}`

From searching I've found this is due to the user email not being verified.

Is there any way that I can verify the user, perhaps by passing an `emailVerified` parameter to `add-user-keycloak.sh` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this will be used in a testing environment, you can use [Keycloak Admin CLI tool](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/). The script is `kcadm.sh` in Linux and `kcadm.bat` in Windows, both under Keycloak's standalone installation `bin` folder. First, you need to get the list of users:

```
./kcadm.sh get users
```

Then, from the output of that command, you extract the `ID` (let us named lets called `<USER_ID>`) of the user that you want to set the `Email Verified` as `ON`.

Then, you just have to execute:

```
./ kcadm.sh update users/<USER_ID> -s 'emailVerified=true'
```

The other option is to use [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_authentication_management_resource)

The first step is to get an admin token, so that you can call the Rest API:

```
curl    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
        -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
        -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
        -d "grant_type=password" \
        https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

You will get a `json response` with the admin token. Extract the **access token** from that response (lets called `$ACCESS_TOKEN`).

Second, you need to get the user `ID`, lets called `$USER_ID.`

```
curl -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$USER_REALM/users/?username=$USERNAME \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Extract from the json response the user `ID`, and change the email verification by calling:

```
curl -k -sS -X PUT https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$USER_REALM/users/$USER_ID \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        -d '{"emailVerified":true}'
```